# What protocol for C server to talk to C# over the internet?

Tags: c, sockets, dll, client-server, tcpclient

What can I use to have a C#-based UI talk to a C-based engine over the internet?

I have a data processing engine dll (which I call the server), written in C, that talks to a user-interface client, written in C#.
While I use the terms "client" and "server" here, I am only using them in the sense that the C#-based UI "talks" to the C-based
engine using P/Invoke.

The client and server both run only in a Windows 64bit environment.  The engine is generic C, and could be recompiled to run on
any OS, but at the moment (and most likely ongoing) I only care about a Windows OS environment.

The UI controls the app, and the engine sits and waits for a request from the UI.  Typically, the engine will sit idle for 90% 
of the time while the app is being used. Once the engine receives a request from the UI, it then
crunches the requested data, and returns the result to the UI.

A relatively small amount of data passes between the UI and the engine.   When the client and engine do talk, the amount of data 
sent by the client to the engine is tiny (less than 1k), and the engine sends back (typically) less than 5k of data.

Given this scenario, what should I use to have the client talk to the engine over the internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What can I use to have a C#-based UI talk to a C-based engine over the internet?

Anything.  Pick a protocol.  Write your own.

[libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) is **cross-platform** and supports a bunch of different net protocols, although it is intended for clients (and WRT internet protocols, you generally do have to distinguish between a client and server applications).  So you could, e.g., implement an HTTP server in the C# app and then an HTTP client in the C app using libcurl.

Networking is a generally a platform specific task, so if you don't use such a library, you'll have to take that into account.  None-the-less, if you think this can be done using your own simple protocol, that should not be too difficult (and may in fact be simpler WRT the server).  It may also be easier if you don't have a grasp on how to use an existing protocol (e.g., exchanging data in HTTP with GET and POST).

Answer (score 0):

Slightly out-there, but worth considering. If you could turn your C code into a Python extension (it's not difficult) then you have lots more options and you can easily evaluate and switch between them. Python has very good networking libraries available and is very happy talking to C code.

For example, you could expose it as an HTTP service (and use WCF in C#) if it fits. Or XMLRPC. Or SOAP. Or plain sockets.

Answer (score 0):

It would require more layers, and thus more work, but I would consider wrapping your server side code in a web service.  This will make the connection to it completely platform independent, allowing you to write new UIs (in any language) in the future with no extra server work.  This is, of course, not always the right move, depending on several factors including the type and quantity of data (you mention small amounts per transaction, but how many transactions?), security concerns and efficiency.  It is, however, a well established platform independent method of transferring data online.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at [protobufs](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/), [thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) and [cap'n proto](http://kentonv.github.io/capnproto/). Maybe too much for what you need, but no harm in looking. Otherwise, you can easily serialize to XML, or JSON or other transfer syntaxes. There are also old timers like [ONC-RPC with XDR](http://www.onc-rpc-xdr.com/).